# nuxt + mdi/js tree shaking not working. how to fix?

Tags: icons, nuxt.js

package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7", 
}, 
"devDependencies": {
  "@mdi/js": "^5.9.55", 
}
```

use

```js
import {mdiPencil} from '@mdi/js'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    mdiPencil
  }),
}
```

I see the whole list in the bundle

> /_nuxt/vendors/pages/index.js
> exports provided: mdiAbTesting, mdiAbacus, mdiAbjadArabic, mdiAbjadHebrew, mdiAbugidaDevanagari, mdiAbugidaThai, mdiAccessPoint, mdiAccessPointCheck, mdiAccessPointMinus, mdiAccessPointNetwork, mdiAccessPointNetworkOff, mdiAccessPointOff, mdiAccessPointPlus ... with svg

project: https://github.com/IceRD/nuxt

Here is the bundlephobia of it: https://bundlephobia.com/package/@mdi/js@5.9.55

Comment: Are you sure the size is coming from `@mdi/js` and not something else?

Comment: i see /_nuxt/vendors/pages/index.js /*! exports provided: mdiAbTesting, mdiAbacus, mdiAbjadArabic, mdiAbjadHebrew, mdiAbugidaDevanagari, mdiAbugidaThai, mdiAccessPoint, mdiAccessPointCheck ... with svg

Comment: Can you try this one and see if the bundle size changes? `import AccountPath from '@mdi/js/Account'`

Comment: @kissu Module not found: Error: Can't resolve